# Clipping raster with different UTM zones using rasterio?

Tags: clip, python-2.7, rasterio

I have 2 Landsat images, with an overlapping area:

[image]

The one on the left is in WGS84 / UTM32N (EPSG:32632), the one on the right is in WGS84 / UTM33N (EPSG: 32633).
I have a polygon in WGS84 / UTM33N (EPSG: 32633). The polygon is located in the overlapping area and I would like to clip each one of the rasters according to my polygon.

Theoretically I should have a problem with the left raster because it is not in the same CRS as the raster, but using clipping tool in QGIS 3 I was able to clip both rasters and the results is satisfying. Each new clipped raster got the same CRS of its 'parent' raster.

The problem rises when I try to perform the same task using `rasterio`:

```
src = r"c:\rasters"
fields_geojson_path = r"C:\Ran\tries\fields\tryField_UTM33N.geojson" 
with fiona.open(fields_geojson_path, "r") as shapefile:
            geoms = [feature["geometry"] for feature in shapefile]
            geoms = list(geoms) #this is because the original file is geojson, if it was shp this needs to be deleted

for i in os.listdir(src):
    if i.endswith('.gz'):
        pass
    else:
        file_list = []

        for j in os.listdir(os.path.join(src,i)):
            if 'stack' not in j:
                if j.endswith('.tif'):
                    date = j.split("_")[3][2:]
                    new_tif = os.path.join(src,i) + "\\"+ date + "_LS8_" + j.split("_")[8].split(".")[0]+".tif"

                    with rasterio.open(os.path.join(src,i) + "\\" + j) as src3:
                        out_image, out_transform = mask(src3, geoms, crop=True, all_touched=True)
                        out_meta = src3.meta.copy()

                    out_meta.update({"driver": "GTiff",
                                     "height": out_image.shape[1],
                                     "width": out_image.shape[2],
                                     "transform": out_transform})

                    with rasterio.open(new_tif, "w", **out_meta) as dest:
                            dest.write(out_image)
src.close
dest.close
print "finish"
```

The clip with the UTM33N raster works fine, but when the iteration get to the UTM32N raster I get:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-61-bf98345b5021> in <module>()
     17 
     18                     with rasterio.open(os.path.join(src,i) + "\\" + j) as src3:
---> 19                         out_image, out_transform = mask(src3, geoms, crop=True, all_touched=True)
     20                         out_meta = src3.meta.copy()
     21 

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\rasterio\tools\mask.pyc in mask(*args, **kwargs)
     10     import warnings
     11     warnings.warn("Deprecated; Use rasterio.mask instead", DeprecationWarning)
---> 12     return rasterio.mask.mask(*args, **kwargs)

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\rasterio\mask.pyc in mask(raster, shapes, nodata, crop, all_touched, invert)
     66     if rasterio.coords.disjoint_bounds(source_bounds, mask_bounds):
     67         if crop:
---> 68             raise ValueError("Input shapes do not overlap raster.")
     69         else:
     70             warnings.warn("GeoJSON outside bounds of existing output " +

ValueError: Input shapes do not overlap raster.
```

How can I do that with Rasterio?

Can I force it to perform it somehow?

My developing platform is Jupyter notebook, Python 2.7 on Windows, so I would prefer some guidance in Python libraries, preferably `Rasterio`.

Comment: For practical examples like this, I tend to retroject the rasters to a common UTM zone. Given that the images overlap, retrojecting the UTM zone 32 to UTM zone 33 won't have any major negative impacts

Comment: Thanks, I can also reproject everything to lat\lon and by doing that eliminating the UTM zones issues, but I would prefer, as I explained in my question, to know if it is possible to "force" Rasterio to perform this kind of clipping without changing the projection of the rasters, just like QGIS does it